# How to connect to mysql-master-ha from my application server

Tags: mysql, high-availability

I am trying to use [mysql-master-ha](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/).

I managed to get it connected with the master and slave mysql servers.

Now I would like to know how to connect to **mysql-master-ha** from my web application server so that the **mysql-master-ha** will automatically switch between master and slave. I can give only one IP address to my application server.

Thanks

Comment: What method are you using to control the virtual IP?

Comment: I am planning to Peacemaker over Ubuntu server. Will that help me?

Comment: Yea, you need to set up a virtual IP in some manner, that would be the IP address your application needs to speak to.

Comment: You're going to need to read a bit on corosync and pacemaker, this talks about setting up the virtual IP http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-crmsh/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_adding_a_resource.html but you'll have to have set up the rest of the software beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to control the mysql resources from within pacemaker, you will also be able to configure a virtual IP controlled by pacemaker. That IP will be the one your application will need to talk to.